# How to allocate a period of time for a thread to execute?

Tags: c++, recursion, stdthread

I have a class executing in a thread.
But I only want to allow it to run for 10 seconds.
Note... I have no means of passing any boolean into the class to stop execution.
So, How can I set up a thread to terminate after 10 seconds?

The class I am testing has potential infinite recursion that may take place and it is pointless to let it run longer than 10 seconds.

```
TEST_METHOD(TM_ClientServer_Threads)
{

  bool bDone = false;
  int ii = 0;

  std::thread tCounter([&bDone, &ii]()
    {
      // Black Box:  can't touch this;  can't pass in a Boolean
      while(true)
      {
        ii++;
      }
    }
  );

  std::thread tTimer([&bDone, &tCounter]()
    {
      Sleep(1000);
      bDone = true;  
      // kill the tCounter thread ?       
    }
  );

  
  tCounter.join();
  tTimer.join();

  ii = ii + 0; // break point here
}
```

Comment: Have the thread periodically stop what it was doing and check the time. If its ten seconds are up, it returns.

Comment: How do I do that?  Once the class is initiated and running, I won't get control back.  The only way I can monitor time is to create another thread and then somehow kill the other thread... not a good idea though

Comment: How about every time it recurses, the first thing it does is check a monotonic clock? If it's out of time it returns a code that tells the caller to bail out. Caller looks at return code and promptly bails and turtles all the way down. You could also throw an exception that's caught in the function initially called by the thread. That means you need to separate the recursive function from the function called by the thread, though, and it's best to save exceptions for exceptional events. If the timeout almost never happens, that's a good place for an exception.

Comment: I have no access to inside the class operations.  So I either set a time limit on a thread some how or kill the thread from another thread that monitors time.

Comment: "*I have no access to inside the class operations*" - Well, then you are SOL, you will just have to "create another thread and then somehow kill the other thread". You are not leaving yourself with very any options here.

Comment: Sounds like you already know this, but I'll drop it anyway for those who follow:  Killing threads is an absolute last resort. There's a lot of stuff you have to know about the thread, what's happening in the thread and what happens in the operating system before you should even consider it. And even if you do, it might still be safer to restart the whole program rather than the thread.

Comment: And that leads to another idea: What if you spin up other processes rather than threads? It's a lot heavier-weight, but you get some good guarantees about and control over what happens when you kill a process.

Comment: @user4581301: Just for the most basic example of the problem, even when your threading API unwisely provides a means of killing threads, if the thread in question was in the middle of a `new`/`malloc` or `delete`/`free` and held the heap lock at the time it was killed, now nothing can allocate or free memory in the process forever. When you need to be able to safely terminate execution from the outside, with no control over the inside, the *only* safe solution is a separate process (where being killed sends all resources back to the OS). On UNIX-likes, `fork`ing's not even that heavyweight.

Comment: I'll add that killing a thread will introduces unintended consequences for any code using thread-local-storage. Killing a thread shouldn't even be a last-resort option at all. **If your program design requires you to kill a thread then your program needs to be redesigned**.